# Asignar nombre de elemento xml con variable for en ellos

Tags: android, android-studio, bucle-for, kotlin

Estoy intentando usar un variable que aumenta para que sea usada para dar una propiedad a un elemento.
El fin es que se asigne un texto diferente a cada elemento de texto.
En si, quiero que la propiedad info_text_nom al final de los ciclos for sea...
info_text_nom0 y
info_text_nom1

Adjunto el código.

```
var respuesta="{ \"personas\" : [ "+

        "{"+
        "\"nombre\":\"Marcos\" ,"+
        "\"pais\":\"México\" ,"+
        "\"estado\":\"soltero\" ," +
        "\"experiencia\":5} ," +

        "{" +

        "\"nombre\":\"Agustín\" ," +
        "\"pais\":\"España\" ," +
        "\"estado\":\"casado\" ," +
        "\"experiencia\" : 16}" +
        " ]"+

        "}"



val json = JSONObject(respuesta)
val personas = json.getJSONArray("personas")
for (i in 0..personas.length()-1){
    val nombre = personas.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")
    val pais = personas.getJSONObject(i).getString("pais")
    val estado = personas.getJSONObject(i).getString("estado")
    val experiencia = personas.getJSONObject(i).getInt("experiencia")

    val persona = Persona(nombre, pais, estado, experiencia)
    info_text_nom(i).text = ""
}
```

> Cita en bloque

Answer (score 0):

Eso no es posible. Lo mejor que puedes hacer sería algo como esto:

```
val textViews = arrayOf<TextView>(info_text_nom0, info_text_nom1, ...)
for (i in 0 until personas.length()) {
    val persona = personas.getJSONObject(i).run {
        Persona(
            nombre = getString("nombre"),
            pais = getString("pais"),
            estado = getString("estado"),
            experiencia = getInt("experiencia"),
        )
    }
    textViews[i].text = persona.nombre
}
```

Aunque sería mejor que usaras librerias para parsear jsons como [kotlinx-serialization](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html), [moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) o [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Además tal vez te interese saber que puedes usar raw strings para no tener que escapar caracteres:

```
val respuesta = """{ 
    "personas": [
        {
            "nombre": "Marcos", 
            "pais": "México", 
            "estado": "soltero",
            "experiencia": 5
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Agustín",
            "pais": "España",
            "estado": "casado",
            "experiencia": 16
        }
    ]
}"""
```